# Autocomplete list in visual basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have microsoft visual basic 2008, And I want to make an automcomplete list for some codes of mine. I know how to do it but the problem that I want it to apear as the program in the main text box so it will be like

```
<html>
<body>
<t
//List here
<tr>
<table>
<td>
```

so I want it to apear under the currently word that I am typing or even get the value of this word to put it in combobox and show the suggested words.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: you know in the program it show to you a list with suggested code I want to make like it!

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is an auto-complete textbox in ASP. A quick google search brought up a number of articles on how to implement this, http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2013/12/autocomplete-textbox-without-webservice.html

Comment: Please don't change your question like this.  It makes any posted answers obsolete.  I have rolled back your question to the previous version.  If you do not need this question, then delete it and post your new question separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the specifics of what you want, but here's something you could do:

1) Add a tooltip to the form.

2) Capture the KeyUp event for the TextBox and within that, assign the ToolTip's value based on whatever TextBox.Text is. If you just want the box's text plus "..." to appear, you could

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(TextBox1, TextBox1.Text.split(" ").last & "...")
End Sub
```

You probably don't really want a tooltip but that's easier than teaching you how to move a label around the screen to follow where you're typing. Maybe try getting that working (but with a function that builds the text of the ToolTip to equal your list of codes/words) and come back with specific questions.

Comment: First: Keep calm this is my first day in scripting in vb
Second: I was using RichTextBox as the tutorial I learnt from
Third: I turned the autocomplete on in the textbox but it don't show the code
Fourth: can you explain more on this as I said **First Day**

Comment: I'm calm. I don't think the fact that your text box is rich will matter much. And Haha -- it's super-cool that I had no idea text boxes had an autocompletemode.

Comment: In all seriousness, you should probably start over with this question. Figure out how to ask it correctly; so that your readers will know what you are looking to do, what you have already done and how *exactly* it isn't working. Include a bit of your code -- as little as possible and as much as necessary.

Comment: After i added a text box instead of rich one it don't show the suggestions words and all I want the sueggestion to apear under the specific word as in the program

Comment: And in your code the problem stay as it is "How to get the value of the last word" cuz if i wrote "Hello Community" it shows for me "Hello community" I want to get "Community" only to check for it in the autocomplete not all the  textbox's text!

Comment: I added .split(" ").last to the TextBox1.Text in the answer above.

Comment: Woked, Thousands Thanks!

Comment: I got the value of the last word and it worked as I want

Comment: Great! If you're done with this question, please wrap it up by accepting my answer (if that's what led you to it) or by writing up an answer of your own with a clear explanation of the solution and accepting that one.